# how to change different environments easily in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, development-environment, production-environment, test-environments

I have an asp.net application that needs to run on different environment such as development, test and production. The site uses a couple of connection strings, 3 web services, different Url paths for OData services, different file upload directories, different passwords for file upload directories and different connection to error logging.

It becomes a real pain whenever I need to change different environment to make sure I have changed everything that needed to change and it becomes very hard to maintain. Some say to keep different web.config files but I don't think it's the best way to solve this problem. Especially when I have to update .svcmap fils for web services I don't think my problem will be solved by keeping multiple web configs. Can anyone suggest me the options I have?